# calculate total used disk space by files older than 180 days using find

Tags: linux, unix, command-line

I am trying to find the total disk space used by files older than 180 days in a particular directory. This is what I'm using:

```
    find . -mtime +180 -exec du -sh {} \;
```

but the above is quiet evidently giving me disk space used by every file that is found. I want only the total added disk space used by the files. Can this be done using `find` and `exec` command ?

Please note I simply don't want to use a script for this, it will be great if there could be a one liner for this. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: If all your files are likely to fit on one command line, then this will work: `find . -mtime +180 -exec du -ch {} \+ | tail -n1` (note the `\+` which means put all the found filenames as arguments - unless they won't all fit, in which case run the command as few times as poss, maximising the files each time).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

@PeterT is right.  Almost all these answers invoke a command (du) for each file, which is very resource intensive and slow and unnecessary.  The simplest and fastest way is this:

```
find . -type f -mtime +356 -printf '%s\n' | awk '{total=total+$1}END{print total/1024}'
```

Answer (score 22):

Why not this?

```
find /path/to/search/in -type f -mtime +180 -print0 | du -hc --files0-from - | tail -n 1
```

Comment: `-type f` helps here as well :)
`find /path/to/search/in -type f -mtime +180 -print0 | du -hc --files0-from - | tail -n 1`

Answer (score 16):

`du` wouldn't summarize if you pass a list of files to it.

Instead, pipe the output to `cut` and let `awk` sum it up.  So you can say:

```
find . -mtime +180 -exec du -ks {} \; | cut -f1 | awk '{total=total+$1}END{print total/1024}'
```

Note that the option `-h` to display the result in human-readable format has been replaced by `-k` which is equivalent to block size of 1K.  The result is presented in MB (see `total/1024` above).

Comment: Actually ```du``` will give you the total of a list of files if you pass it the ```-c``` option but there could easily be too many files.

Comment: Should add `-type f` otherwise it will include current directory `.` total size to result.

Comment: **This gives incorrect results** without `-type f` as suggested above

Comment: This solution has many flaws, and should be never used:
1) Bug mentioned in other comments
2) It is *very* slow, as it executes du for every single file
3) awk may not be able to handle large enough integers
*Please revoke this as accepted answer* and accept the answer by user2059857.

Answer (score 8):

Be careful not to take into account the disk usage by the directories. For example, I have a lot of files in my `~/tmp` directory:

```
$ du -sh ~/tmp
3,7G    /home/rpet/tmp
```

Running the first part of example posted by [devnull](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2235132/devnull) to find the files modified in the last 24 hours, we can see that `awk` will sum the whole disk usage of the `~/tmp` directory:

```
$ find ~/tmp -mtime 0 -exec du -ks {} \; | cut -f1
3849848
84
80
```

But there is only one file modified in that period of time, with very little disk usage:

```
$ find ~/tmp -mtime 0
/home/rpet/tmp
/home/rpet/tmp/kk
/home/rpet/tmp/kk/test.png

$ du -sh ~/tmp/kk
84K /home/rpet/tmp/kk
```

So we need to take into account only the files and exclude the directories:

```
$ find ~/tmp -type f -mtime 0 -exec du -ks {} \; | cut -f1 | awk '{total=total+$1}END{print total/1024}'
0.078125
```

You can also specify date ranges using the `-newermt` parameter. For example:

```
$ find . -type f -newermt "2014-01-01" ! -newermt "2014-06-01"
```

See http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/8721/find-files-in-a-date-range

Comment: surely `find ... \+` is far more efficient?

Comment: for me, `find . -type f -newermt "2015-08-08" ! -newermt "2016-09-09" -exec du -ks {} \; | cut -f1 | awk '{total=total+$1}END{print total/1024}'`
 did the trick, thank you! ;)

Answer (score 6):

You can print file size with `find` using the `-printf` option, but you still need `awk` to sum.

For example, total size of all files older than 365 days:

```
find . -type f -mtime +356 -printf '%s\n' \
     | awk '{a+=$1;} END {printf "%.1f GB\n", a/2**30;}'
```

Comment: I actually liked this answer the best. I modified -mtime to -10 for files newer than 10 days, but yours was the easiest to follow. Thanks.