# Calculate disk usage on bash. sum of files bigger than space used,

Tags: bash, du

I'm trying to calculate he size used by the files created during the last 365 days

Using the information provided by this answer
[calculate total used disk space by files older than 180 days using find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419337/calculate-total-used-disk-space-by-files-older-than-180-days-using-find)

```
find . -type f -mtime -1 -printf '%s\n' | awk '{total=total+$1}END{print total/1024}'
```

It must work, but the results not mach with the expectation, the result is higher than the folder size.

So I made a simple test with just one folder, without the filters by date.

```
[log]$ du
601407  .
[log]$ find . -type f -printf '%s\n' | awk '{total=total+$1}END{print total/1024}'
720779
```

The result of DU is bigger than the individual SUM of files.
Why?

My folder contains thousand of files < 10Kbytes on several subfolders. Is related to some minimum cluster size?

Comment: Duplicate of : https://superuser.com/questions/94217/why-ls-and-du-show-different-size.

Comment: `%s` shows the file's size in bytes. `du` calculates the disk space in blocks. If a file is only 1 byte, it still uses a full disk block.

Comment: Hi @Barmar but %s is bigger than du... if du gets the disk space in blocks, should be bigger....

Comment: Right. `du` doesn't count the skipped blocks in sparse files, see the linked question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
du --apparent-size
```

Solve my problem as pointed by @matias-barrios and @barmar

More info at https://superuser.com/questions/94217/why-ls-and-du-show-different-size