# calculate in TB total used disk space by files newer than X days using find

Tags: awk, find, command, printf, filemtime

I have a folder with thousands of large files and I would like to find the total used disk space that was created in the last X days.

I've tried this command:

```
find . -type f -mtime -30 -printf '%s\n' | awk '{total=total+$1}END{print total/1024}'
```

As mentioned here by @k-h
[calculate total used disk space by files older than 180 days using find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419337/calculate-total-used-disk-space-by-files-older-than-180-days-using-find)

The output of the command is 9.84347e+09 and I'm not sure how to change the output to TB disk size.

Please advise.
Thanks,
Yaron

Comment: This might help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44040/a-standard-tool-to-convert-a-byte-count-into-human-kib-mib-etc-like-du-ls1

Comment: Are you interested in the file-size or the disk-space ... these are two different things.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. You would like to have your results printed in TB and you have your hands on a command that prints the results in kB (`%s` returns bytes (see `man find`) ) ... So it seems to me that this is a straightforward task. I'm very convinced you can handle this.

Comment: ill try @kvantour, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well not quite the same logic but I'm here to explain:

```
{ echo -n \(; find -type f -mtime -30 -printf "%s+"; echo 0\)/1024/1024/1024/1024; } | bc
```

Let's break this down:

- `echo -n \(` - prints `(` without a line break.
- `find …` - that same ol' command you used with the `+` sign for calculation.
- `echo 0\)/1024…` - we're printing `0` so the expression won't end with a `+` sign, print the closing parentheses and then dividing by 1024 four times to get to the relevant result.
- `| bc` - this is the calculation tool, you can simply pipe the formula to this tool, try running `echo 1+2 | bc` and play with it to understand its concept.

Have fun, and cool name BTW :)

Comment: Thank you @yaron